# Last scene of the movie American Sniper

Tags: plot-explanation, ending, american-sniper

Is there any significance of the last scene in the movie *American Sniper*, when Taya (Chris Kyle's wife) stares at the person standing near the car for some time?

Answer (score 5):

Kyle was trying to help a veteran who ended up killing him as is disclosed the final text overlay and it's implied that the man in the scene is (or represents) Eddie Ray Routh, the perpetrator.

Clearly Taya has some misgivings about the man (or at least the movie wants us to think so).

> Years later, on February 2, 2013, Kyle says goodbye to his wife and family as he leaves in good spirits to **spend time with a veteran at a shooting range.** An on-screen subtitle reveals: "Chris Kyle was killed that day by a veteran he was trying to help".
>
> <sup>[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Sniper)</sup>

[image]

More...

> Chris Kyle had begun working with veterans after leaving the military. Routh's mother, who worked at the school that Kyle's children attended, had heard of his work and asked him to help her son. **He agreed to take Routh to a shooting range, which Kyle believed had therapeutic value.**
>
> On February 2, 2013, Kyle and his friend, Chad Littlefield, 35, were shot and killed by Eddie Ray Routh at the Rough Creek Ranch-Lodge-Resort shooting range in Erath County, Texas. Both Kyle and Littlefield were armed with .45-caliber M1911-style pistols when they were killed, but neither gun had been unholstered or fired, and the safety catches were still on. Kyle was killed with a .45-caliber pistol, while Littlefield was shot with a 9mm SIG Sauer P226 Mk.25 Mod 0 pistol. Both guns belonged to Kyle.
>
> Routh was a 25-year-old U.S. Marine Corps veteran from Lancaster, Texas. Kyle and Littlefield had reportedly taken Routh to the gun range in an effort to help him with his post-traumatic stress disorder (PTSD). Routh had been in and out of mental hospitals for at least two years and had been diagnosed with schizophrenia.
>
> <sup>[**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murders_of_Chris_Kyle_and_Chad_Littlefield#Perpetrator)</sup>